# Access to redux state in callback, after async actions

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, event-handling

I'm trying to make a simple signin/CRUD project with React and Django.

Assume that we have redux store for handling user information and posts.

For signin or create post, I should send request to backend, wait the response,
and update the state of frontend. I tried to implement it with redux's `createAsyncThunk`.
And used it in click handler of button (login or create post).
But the state is not updated properly.

Specifically, the state is updated one step later.

Here's the minimal working example.
As I commented, `axios.get("/api/id/")` returns just a random integer.
And `store.getState().api.id` works in this example, but not worked in real project code.

```js
// App.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectApi, getid } from "./store/slices/api";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { store } from "./store";

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const apiState = useSelector(selectApi);
    const [ID, setID] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setID(apiState.id);
        console.log(`In useeffect: ${ID}`);
    }, [apiState, ID]);

    // they are same
    const onclick = async () => {
        const x = await dispatch(getid()); 
        console.log(x.payload.id); // this works.
        console.log(apiState.id); // not works
        console.log(ID); // not works
        console.log(store.getState().api.id); // worked in this example, but not worked in real project.
    };
    // const onclick = () => {
    //  dispatch(getid())
    //      .unwrap()
    //      .then((res) => {
    //          console.log(res.id);
    //          console.log(apiState.id);
    //          console.log(ID);
    //          console.log(store.getState().api.id);
    //      });
    // };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <div>Hello</div>
                <button onClick={onclick}>Click</button>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// store/index.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import apiReducer from "./slices/api";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        api: apiReducer,
    },
});
```

```js
// store/slices/api.js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const initialState = {
    id: 0,
};

export const getid = createAsyncThunk("api/add", async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/id/"); // just gives random integer
    return {
        id: response.data,
    };
});

export const apiSlice = createSlice({
    name: "api",
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getid.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.id = action.payload.id;
        });
    },
});

export const apiActions = apiSlice.actions;
export const selectApi = (state) => state.api;
export default apiSlice.reducer;
```

If I click button two times and if server returns 41, 90

Then output becomes

```
---------- First Click ---------
In useeffect: 0
41
0
0
41
In useeffect: 41 
---------- Second Click ---------
In useeffect: 41
90
41
41
90
In useeffect: 90
```

And also, output of `useEffect` are different in real project code(worked properly in that case).

I expected that expressions and
statement after `await` (or in `then` callback) should be executed after finishing state update,
but it didn't.
Moreover, I tried to use `useCallback` and add state to its dependency list, but
if I try that way, then `dispatch` didn't even executed.
I refered [official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#async-requests-with-createasyncthunk) and some googling results, but it not helped.

I want to access state by redux store, rather than using return value of async thunk, because of some coding-style reasons:

1. Other features (such as get post) just uses redux store, I want to write code with simple and unified style.
2. If I change the spec of api, then I should change event handler also, and (maybe) it does not return value.
3. In real project, I use typescript, and there's some issues about typing the return value of async thunk.

How can I access state after properly updated in callback?

Comment: Your `useEffect` in depending on your `ID` to change, but you're using `setID` this will cause a loop

Comment: That's not a cause of problem. I already tested all combinations of deps and it not helped.

Comment: @RubenSmn
And since it updates one step later, it does not seem to be caused by loop.
Moreover, adding `ID` to dependency is eslint's recommendation.